# Genesis - Customize search form

Tags: php, search, forms, genesis-theme-framework

I wanted to change my search form a bit by adding `autocomplete="off"` to the search input.

I initially looked for a simple filter like the following:

```
//* Customize search form input box text
add_filter( 'genesis_search_text', 'sp_search_text' );
function sp_search_text( $text ) {
    return esc_attr( 'Search my blog...' );
}
```

But because the `/genesis/lib/structure/search.php` did not have any variable like `autocomplete="%s"`, that attribute could not be targeted. I probably had to introduce it directly, so I copied the `search.php` from the parent theme folder to the child theme folder folder.

The original code of the file was the following:

```
<?php

/**
 * Replace the default search form with a Genesis-specific form.
 *
 * The exact output depends on whether the child theme supports HTML5 or not.
 *
 * Applies the `genesis_search_text`, `genesis_search_button_text`, `genesis_search_form_label` and
 * `genesis_search_form` filters.
 *
 * @since 0.2.0
 *
 * @return string HTML markup for search form.
 */

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'genesis_search_form' );

function genesis_search_form() {
    $search_text = get_search_query() ? apply_filters( 'the_search_query', get_search_query() ) : apply_filters( 'genesis_search_text', __( 'Search this website', 'genesis' ) . ' &#x02026;' );

    $button_text = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_button_text', esc_attr__( 'Search', 'genesis' ) );

    $onfocus = "if ('" . esc_js( $search_text ) . "' === this.value) {this.value = '';}";
    $onblur  = "if ('' === this.value) {this.value = '" . esc_js( $search_text ) . "';}";

    // Empty label, by default. Filterable.
    $label = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_form_label', '' );

    $value_or_placeholder = ( get_search_query() == '' ) ? 'placeholder' : 'value';

    if ( genesis_html5() ) {

        $form  = sprintf( '<form %s>', genesis_attr( 'search-form' ) );

        if ( genesis_a11y( 'search-form' ) ) {

            if ( '' == $label )  {
                $label = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_text', __( 'Search this website', 'genesis' ) );
            }

            $form_id = uniqid( 'searchform-' );

            $form .= sprintf(
                '<meta itemprop="target" content="%s"/><label class="search-form-label screen-reader-text" for="%s">%s</label><input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" id="%s" %s="%s" /><input type="submit" value="%s" /></form>',
                home_url( '/?s={s}' ),
                esc_attr( $form_id ),
                esc_html( $label ),
                esc_attr( $form_id ),
                $value_or_placeholder,
                esc_attr( $search_text ),
                esc_attr( $button_text )
            );

        } else {

            $form .= sprintf(
                '%s<meta itemprop="target" content="%s"/><input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" %s="%s" /><input type="submit" value="%s"  /></form>',
                esc_html( $label ),
                home_url( '/?s={s}' ),
                $value_or_placeholder,
                esc_attr( $search_text ),
                esc_attr( $button_text )
            );
        }


    } else {

        $form = sprintf(
            '<form method="get" class="searchform search-form" action="%s" role="search" >%s<input type="text" value="%s" name="s" class="s search-input" onfocus="%s" onblur="%s" /><input type="submit" class="searchsubmit search-submit" value="%s" /></form>',
            home_url( '/' ),
            esc_html( $label ),
            esc_attr( $search_text ),
            esc_attr( $onfocus ),
            esc_attr( $onblur ),
            esc_attr( $button_text )
        );

    }

    return apply_filters( 'genesis_search_form', $form, $search_text, $button_text, $label );

}
```

Then I removed the original filter and added my filter:

```
remove_filter( 'get_search_form', 'genesis_search_form' );

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_search_form' );
```

And added `autocomplete="off"` to the search input, so the current is:

```
<?php

/**
 * Replace the default search form with a Genesis-specific form.
 *
 * The exact output depends on whether the child theme supports HTML5 or not.
 *
 * Applies the `genesis_search_text`, `genesis_search_button_text`, `genesis_search_form_label` and
 * `genesis_search_form` filters.
 *
 * @since 0.2.0
 *
 * @return string HTML markup for search form.
 */

remove_filter( 'get_search_form', 'genesis_search_form' );

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_search_form' );

function my_search_form() {
    $search_text = get_search_query() ? apply_filters( 'the_search_query', get_search_query() ) : apply_filters( 'genesis_search_text', __( 'Search this website', 'genesis' ) . ' &#x02026;' );

    $button_text = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_button_text', esc_attr__( 'Search', 'genesis' ) );

    $onfocus = "if ('" . esc_js( $search_text ) . "' === this.value) {this.value = '';}";
    $onblur  = "if ('' === this.value) {this.value = '" . esc_js( $search_text ) . "';}";

    // Empty label, by default. Filterable.
    $label = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_form_label', '' );

    $value_or_placeholder = ( get_search_query() == '' ) ? 'placeholder' : 'value';

    if ( genesis_html5() ) {

        $form  = sprintf( '<form %s>', genesis_attr( 'search-form' ) );

        if ( genesis_a11y( 'search-form' ) ) {

            if ( '' == $label )  {
                $label = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_text', __( 'Search this website', 'genesis' ) );
            }

            $form_id = uniqid( 'searchform-' );

            $form .= sprintf(
                '<meta itemprop="target" content="%s"/><label class="search-form-label screen-reader-text" for="%s">%s</label><input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" id="%s" %s="%s" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" dir="auto" /><input type="submit" value="%s" /></form>',
                home_url( '/?s={s}' ),
                esc_attr( $form_id ),
                esc_html( $label ),
                esc_attr( $form_id ),
                $value_or_placeholder,
                esc_attr( $search_text ),
                esc_attr( $button_text )
            );

        } else {

            $form .= sprintf(
                '%s<meta itemprop="target" content="%s"/><input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" %s="%s" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" dir="auto" /><input type="submit" value="%s"  /></form>',
                esc_html( $label ),
                home_url( '/?s={s}' ),
                $value_or_placeholder,
                esc_attr( $search_text ),
                esc_attr( $button_text )
            );
        }


    } else {

        $form = sprintf(
            '<form method="get" class="searchform search-form" action="%s" role="search" >%s<input type="text" value="%s" name="s" class="s search-input" onfocus="%s" onblur="%s" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" dir="auto" /><input type="submit" class="searchsubmit search-submit" value="%s" /></form>',
            home_url( '/' ),
            esc_html( $label ),
            esc_attr( $search_text ),
            esc_attr( $onfocus ),
            esc_attr( $onblur ),
            esc_attr( $button_text )
        );

    }

    return apply_filters( 'my_search_form', $form, $search_text, $button_text, $label );

}
```

It currently works perfectly on the homepage, but in any other page only the header and the tagline are generated.

---

**Update**

I've done some testing and found the source of the issue where the pages were not generated, it was having this in `functions.php`, retrieved from this [site](http://wpbeaches.com/adding-fly-search-field-box-genesis-based-twentyfourteen/):

```
//* Add the search bar
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'sp_menu_items', 10, 2 );
function sp_menu_items( $items, $args ) {

    $items .= sprintf( '<li id="sb" class="menu-item sb">%s</li>', get_search_form( false ) );
    return $items;

}
```

and having the current code I was testing in the `searchform.php`, retrieved from this [site](http://rickrduncan.com/wordpress/customize-genesis-search-form)

```
<?php

add_filter( 'genesis_search_form', 'my_search_form', 10, 1);
function my_search_form( $form ) {

$search_text = get_search_query() ? apply_filters( 'the_search_query', get_search_query() ) : apply_filters( 'genesis_search_text', __( 'Search this website', 'genesis' ) . ' &#x02026;' );

$button_text = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_button_text', esc_attr__( 'Search', 'genesis' ) );

$onfocus = "if ('" . esc_js( $search_text ) . "' === this.value) {this.value = '';}";
$onblur  = "if ('' === this.value) {this.value = '" . esc_js( $search_text ) . "';}";

// Empty label, by default. Filterable.
$label = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_form_label', '' );

$value_or_placeholder = ( get_search_query() == '' ) ? 'placeholder' : 'value';

$form = sprintf(
            '<form class="search-form"><meta itemprop="target" content="%s"/><label class="search-form-label screen-reader-text" for="%s">%s</label><input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" id="%s" placeholder="%s" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" dir="auto" /><input type="submit" value="%s" /></form>',
            home_url( '/?s={s}' ),
            esc_attr( $form_id ),
            esc_html( $label ),
            esc_attr( $form_id ),
            esc_attr( $search_text ),
            esc_attr( $button_text )
        );

return $form;

}
```

Removing any or using both in `functions.php` will result in all pages displaying correctly. Any idea why?

---

[Documentation for get_search_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/)

[Documentation for genesis_search_form](http://genesis.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/genesis_search_form/)

[Documentation for Genesis Snippets](http://my.studiopress.com/documentation/snippets)

Comment: Where is your `my_search_form()` function you use in the `add_filter()`? And what kind of errors?

Comment: In the searchform.php I remove the original `genesis_search_form()` filter and replace all instances of `genesis_search_form()` with `my_search_form()` and add the `autocomplete="off"` to the code. The errors are error 500 where the entire or parts of the page appear white, it seems that the code can't run properly outside of its original location, but I wanted an alternative to avoid editing the parent theme framework directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting a 500 error. Likely because you're trying to use a function before it's been defined.

But I think you're going about the problem the wrong way. Genesis *does* provide a filter before returning the search form. Why not just add a filter to the `genesis_search_form` hook?

You can add the filter to your child theme functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_search_form', function( $form, $search_text, $button_text, $label ) { 
  return str_replace( 
    'type="search"', 
    'type="search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" dir="auto"', 
    $form 
  );
}, 10, 4 );
```

Alternate (untested, but it should work) method using `substr_replace()`:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_search_form', function( $form, $search_text, $button_text, $label ) { 
  $insert = ' autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" dir="auto"';
  $needle = 'type="search"';
  $where = strpos( $form, $needle ) + strlen( $needle );
  return substr_replace( $form, $insert, $where, 0 );
}, 10, 4 );
```

---

You're getting a 500 error because you can't have a function as an argument in `sprintf()`. Try this:

```
//* Add the search bar
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'sp_menu_items', 10, 2 );
function sp_menu_items( $items, $args ) {
    $form = get_search_form( false );
    $items .= sprintf( '<li id="sb" class="menu-item sb">%s</li>', $form );
    return $items;

}
```

Comment: I have an edit in the que. This didn't work so it was corrected as follows: `add_filter( 'genesis_search_form', function( $form ) { 
  return str_replace( 
    'type="search"', 
    'type="search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" dir="auto"', 
    $form 
  );
}, 10, 4);
`

Comment: @Christina, Nathan - That looks very neat and simple, it's the best solution so far. I found the source of the initial conflict, would you mind looking at it, please?

Comment: The second code has the same effect of not generating the bottom of the pages that are not homepage. the most awkward thing is that if both the of codes of adding and modifying are in the functions.php it displays fine. I added the sites where I based my codes.

Comment: That code _should_ be in your functions.php file not searchform.php. See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Theme_Forms). searchform.php is for styling the form.

Comment: Alright, thank you! One last comment before resolving this. Before I did not have printf, I added it to test, I had ' . get_search_form( false ) . ' would that be better? And the first code is really neat, but in `str_replace` isn't there a way to insert instead of replacing? and that is all, thank you very much.

Comment: Whether you concatenate or use sprintf() is personal preference. I like sprintf(). Re: str_replace(), basically the code is saying, if there's type="search" in the string, insert something behind it. You could use substr_replace(). They both will get the job done.

Comment: All right, really good code. I guess that `str_replace` is a good option because is used for both targeting and inserting.